# How to dynamically indicate the properties of a button in a SWIFT function

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a function that changes the background colors of a label but since the label could be one of many, I need to pass the label name and them construct it in the function.  Something like:

```
selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
```

where **selectedLabel** is the name of the label being passed. Currently I get an error on the `selectedLabel` that "Value of type '`String`' has no member"

See the code below:

```
@IBAction func btn1B(sender: AnyObject)
{

    let passedLabel = "btn1B"
    changeColor (passedLabel)

}
```

/**************************************************/

```
func changeColor (selectedLabel: String)
{
    switch nextColor
    {
    case 0: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
    case 1: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    case 2: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    case 3: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
    case 4: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    case 5: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    case 6: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    case 7: selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
    default: print("end of colors")
    }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just pass a reference to the label rather than a string...?

Comment: Seems to me like you don't understand some very important core concepts yet, I suggest you follow some tutorials or read some books about basic programming.

Comment: Thank you nhgrif.  I took your suggestion and it works fine!  Being new to SWIFT is daunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string as an argument, so it is not going to work.

METHOD 1:
Pass the label object instead. Link the label to a class property:

```
// MARK: properties
@IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel

// MARK: actions
@IBAction func btn1B(sender: AnyObject)
{

    changeColor(self.yourlabel)

}
```

METHOD 2 (not as good as method1): you could find your label with an id that you set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of the one variable, `btn1B` it looks like you are changing the color of the button itself rather than a separate label. If that's the case change the type of `sender` from `AnyObject` to `UIButton` and then use only one action method for all the buttons that contains the code from `changeColor()` changing every occurrence of `selectedLabel` with `sender`.

If you do have a separate label for each button that is named something along the lines of `btn1B` then lose the quotes from the first line of `btn1B()` and change the type in `changeColor()` from `String` to `UILabel`.